# GAM: mgcv model with kurtosis: Does this need to be solved and how?

Tags: normal-distribution, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, kurtosis

I am trying to model CO2 fluxes (fco2) using a number of environmental parameters using a GAM in mgcv. Specifically, I have leaf temperature (tl), vapour pressure deficit (vpd), and transpiration (tr).

```
m <- gam(co2 ~ ti(vpd, tr) + s(tl) + s(tr, k=3), data=df, method='REML', select=T)
```

I am getting the best model AIC and R-squared when I use k=3 on s(tr). However, when I check the model using `gam.check`, I'm seeing strong kurtosis. Is this an fundamental issue, and how can I solve it if it is? Thanks

[image: Histogram]

[image: QQ plot]

[image: Residuals vs. linear prediction]

[image: Response vs. fitted]

Comment: Try using a T distribution to model the errors.

Comment: That didn't work at all...

Comment: Surprised- it looks symmetric and heavy- tailed, just like a t. What df was estimated? How did the log likelihood change?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified: I used `family=scat(link="identity")`. It works, but drops R-squared from 0.50 to 0.35. I assume that my model assumptions are not great using this distribution, hence the drop in R-squared, but now I'm wondering how I can get that to increase again